# cpp newbie question: error: conversion to ‘std::array<int, 5>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to implement my own swap function for array, but it seems to have conversion problem.
And I do not have a clue.
Forgive me if this question is too stupid.

Here is the source code:

x_quiz3.h

```
#include<array>

using namespace std;

void swap_arr_element(array<int,5> &arr, int index1, int index2){
    int temp{arr.at(index1)};
    arr.at(index1) = arr.at(index2);
    arr.at(index2) = temp;
}

void start_x_quiz3(){
    array arr{1,2,4,3,5};
    swap_arr_element(arr, 2, 3);
    for (auto &i : arr){
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "x_quiz3.h"

int main()
{
    start_x_quiz3();
    return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
||=== Build: Debug in chapter6 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/lewisluk/CodeBlocksProjects/tutorials/quizs/chapter6/x_quiz3.h||In function ‘void swap_arr_element(std::array<int, 5>&, int, int)’:|
/home/lewisluk/CodeBlocksProjects/tutorials/quizs/chapter6/x_quiz3.h|8|error: conversion to ‘std::array<int, 5>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]|
/home/lewisluk/CodeBlocksProjects/tutorials/quizs/chapter6/x_quiz3.h|9|error: conversion to ‘std::array<int, 5>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]|
/home/lewisluk/CodeBlocksProjects/tutorials/quizs/chapter6/x_quiz3.h|9|error: conversion to ‘std::array<int, 5>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]|
/home/lewisluk/CodeBlocksProjects/tutorials/quizs/chapter6/x_quiz3.h|10|error: conversion to ‘std::array<int, 5>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) function is `size_type`, which is an *unsigned* type.

The index arguments to your swap function are `int` which is a *signed* type.

The compiler says that it can not safely convert from a signed type to an unsigned type (which it can't, think about what happens if you provide negative indexes).

The simple solution is to make the swap function index arguments *unsigned* as well, preferably using the `size_t` type:

```
void swap_arr_element(array<int,5> &arr, size_t index1, size_t index2){ ... }
```

Comment: It _can_ safely convert (unsigned arithmetic wraps around). This is just a warning, promoted to an error by `Werror`. The simple solution is to turn off that warning. The arguments _should_ be `size_t` though you're right